# Chi-square independence test for A/B split testing

Tags: chi-squared-test, ab-test

I have the results of an A/B split test of a web page.

```
Page  Impressions   Clicks    CTR       
A     56,000        10        0.018%    
B     78,000        21        0.027%
```

I'd like to test the ctr for statistically significant difference. Null hypothesis - there is no difference in CTR between pages A & B.

How would I go about doing this on a more theoretical level? As in what should be rows, column, setting expected values?

Comment: Is `CTR` simply `Clicks/Impressions`? If so, why not say so in your question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one way to lay out the chi-squared test -- you don't necessarily need all this detail. The test doesn't care which way around you have rows and columns, so I'll do it 
your way around.

```
Comparing proportions via Pearson's Chi-squared test of independence
at the 5% level      #(for this example, at least - you choose your own level)

Null hypothesis - there is no difference in CTR between pages A & B.

Observed:
   Clicks   Nonclicks     Impressions 
A     10       55990           56000
B     21       77979           78000

Tot   31      133969          134000

Expected:
   Clicks   Nonclicks     Impressions 
A   12.96    55987.04          56000
B   18.04    77981.96          78000

Tot   31      133969          134000
```

(Entries in the body of the Expected table are row.total*column.total/overall.total)

Contribution to chi-square = (Observed - Expected)^2/Expected

```
       Clicks   Nonclicks   
 A     0.6741   0.0001560
 B     0.4840   0.0001120

Chi-square = sum((Observed - Expected)^2/Expected)
           = 1.158368

 df = 1
 p-value = 0.2818  

 At the 5% level we do not reject H0 - there's no evidence of a difference in
 click through rate.
```

(You need tables or a program to find the p-value.)

Answer (score 0):

The chi-square test of independence only tests for whether there is a relationship between the variables, though, not that there is no difference between CTR:

H0: Click-through and interface are independent.
Ha: Click-through and interface are *not* independent (that is, something interesting is going on; one of your interfaces is performing better)

You would prepare the test like this:

```
success <- c(10,21)
failure <- c(55990,77979)
my.table <- rbind(success,failure)
```

And then run the test:

```
> chisq.test(my.table)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  my.table
X-squared = 0.79955, df = 1, p-value = 0.3712
```

You get the same results as the previous respondent when you turn off the continuity correction (which many argue you don't need at all, unless you have less than 5 clicks on either A or B):

```
> chisq.test(my.table, correct=FALSE)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  my.table
X-squared = 1.1584, df = 1, p-value = 0.2818
```

You can easily access your expected value table and compute the chi-square test statistic manually if you want:

```
> chisq.test(my.table, correct=FALSE)$expected
               [,1]        [,2]
success    12.95522    18.04478
failure 55987.04478 77981.95522
```

An alternative would be the two-proportion zitest, which says:

H0: CTR of B - CTR of A = 0
Ha: CTR of B - CTR of A > 0  (B has a bigger CTR)

```
> source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NicoleRadziwill/R-Functions/master/z2test.R")
> z2.test(10,55990,21,77979)
$estimate
[1] -9.069995e-05

$ts.z
[1] -1.076516

$p.val
[1] 0.1408483

$cint
[1] -2.504372e-04  6.903728e-05
```

Notice that the p-value is large (0.14) and the confidence interval includes the value zero -- there's no difference between your A and B CTRs.

You could also use a chi-square test statistic to run the test and get a confidence interval:

```
> prop.test(c(10,21),c(55990,77979))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(10, 21) out of c(55990, 77979)
X-squared = 0.79999, df = 1, p-value = 0.3711
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.657756e-04  8.437566e-05
sample estimates:
      prop 1       prop 2 
0.0001786033 0.0002693033
```

Notice that the p-value is the same as when you ran the chi-square test of independence earlier, and the confidence interval also includes zero in it.... indicating no significant difference between CTRs for your A and B.