# What statistical test to use for A/B testing

Tags: t-test, chi-squared-test, ab-test

I'm trying to understand how A/B testing works for a simple 2x2 contingency table.

I have found two different types of solutions:

1) Calculate an aggregate probability of conversion assuming that there is no difference in the conversion rate between version A and version B.  Then, perform a chi-squared goodness-of-fit test between the actual results in the 2x2 table vs the predicted results (assuming no difference).
(see: [Chi-square independence test for A/B split testing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63518/chi-square-independence-test-for-a-b-split-testing))

2) 
`((Prob_conversion(A) - Prob_conversion(B))/sqrt(Standard_deviation(Prob_conversion(A))^2 + Standard_deviation(Prob_conversion(B))^2)`

should have a N(0,1) distribution.

I feel like method 1) and 2) must be linked somehow.  Can someone explain how?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes. The z distribution and the Chi-Sq distribution are related.  With respect to your question, with 1 d.f., Chi Square = z squared.

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks for your answer.  Does it mean that the two methods I described are equivalent?

Comment: Yes. You can do the analyses both ways and compare the values of the test statistics.  Chi-sq should be equal to the square of z.